# Is it possible to change the displayName of a Context.Consumer?

Tags: reactjs, react-context, react-16

How can I find my way around nested Contexts and avoid this hell?

[image]

Comment: how did that even happen?

Comment: Well as of now there isn't a way in react-devtools to separate out the Context displayname, there is an open issue on the same https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools/issues/1008

Answer (score 1):

This works (at least on React v16.3.0+):

```
SomeContext.Consumer.displayName = "SomeContext.Consumer";
SomeContext.Provider.displayName = "SomeContext.Provider";
```